# Why is this continuous function not differentiable?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Let $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that
\begin{equation}
  g(x)=\begin{cases}
    2x + 1 & \text{ if } x < 0,\\
    e^x & \text{ otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I am trying to understand the properties of this function.
I already know that it is continuous, as its' components are continuous functions(because $2x+1$ is linear and $e^x$ is exponential).

But I don't understand why it is not differentiable, because I think that the derivates of both of the component functions exist at any given point within the specified ranges ($x<0$ for $2x + 1$ and $x \geq 0$ for $e^x$).

Can you please explain the differentiability of this function?

Comment: Your justfication that the function is continuous is certainly not valid. Graph the function. Does it look differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: But isnt' this true, at x = 0, g(0)' = e^0 = 1? I don't understand why it is not differentiable at x = 0.

Comment: Is $f(x)=\begin{cases} 2x, & x<0 \\ e^x, & x\ge 0\end{cases}$ continuous? What is the derivative of $y=2x$?

Comment: it has derivative 2 as x approaches 0 from below and 1 as x approaches 0 from above, therefore it is not differentiable at x = 0.

Comment: But linear functions and exponential functions are continuous for real numbers, so aren't 2x+1(or 2x) and e^x also continuous, and since they are, also the function?

Comment: @Colver so it is not differentiable, because the left- and right-hand derivatives of the function g(x) differ as they approach 0.

Comment: Regarding continuity of a function defined piecewise, just because the components are continuous does not mean that the whole function is continuous. With the example in the comments, take the limit as $x$ goes to zero from the left and right. What do you get?

Comment: lim x->0 2x = 0 from the left and lim x->0 e^x = 1 from the right.

Comment: @ppch: *not differentiable, because the left- and right-hand derivatives of the function g(x) differ as they approach 0* --- This only tells us that if the derivative exists, then it is not continuous at $0.$ It doesn't imply that the function is not differentiable at $0.$ For example, $f(x)=x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ for $x\neq 0$, with $f(0)=0,$ IS differentiable at $x=0,$ but what you said (the "differ" stuff) appears to apply. The reason I'm saying appears is because "differ as they approach 0" is a bit unclear -- away from $x=0$ **continued)**

Comment: the left-derivative equals the two-sided derivative and the right-derivative equals the two-sided derivative (each of these two assertions is true for the OP's function and for the function I gave), so "as they approach 0" seems to mean the limit of the derivative for $x \rightarrow 0.$

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of the left-half of the function $(2x+1)$ is $2$. The derivative of the right-half of the function for all other $x$-values is $e^x$. Using this information, we can formulate another piecewise function that shows the derivative of $g(x)$.

$g'(x)=
\begin{cases}
2 \,, & \text{for} \;\;\; x \lt 0\\
e^x \,, & \text{for} \;\;\; x \ge 0
\end{cases}
$

This function seems to support the original claim you made. It clearly shows that $g'(x)$ exists for all real numbers, including $x=0$. However, this is a trap! We have to look at the derivative in the context of the original function. At $x=0$, $g(x)$ has a sharp cusp, which makes it impossible to predict the behavior of the function around that point. And that ruins the whole point of the derivative. If I showed you the function $g(x)$ with the right-half erased, and asked you to draw a line continuing the slope of the left-half, you would probably draw a line continuing with a slope of $2$. It would be impossible for you to know that the right-half follows the slope of $e^x$ instead of $2x+1$.

Also, if you're familiar with the concept of tangent lines showing the instantaneous slope of a function, there would be infinitely many possible tangent lines at $g(0)$, making it impossible to agree on the slope at that point.